# Simple TRUE code converted to FALSE

Tags: php, false-positive

I know I am supposed to explain a lot but this is so simple that I don't even understand why I can't get it right.

This piece of code is supposed to be FALSE and not TRUE;

```
if ($ip == $yourip && $ban == 1)
```

I have tried this:

```
if (!$ip == $yourip && !$ban == 1)
```

And this...

```
if ($ip != $yourip && $ban != 1)
```

With no luck? I just simply need it to be the opposite of what it is.

Comment: Please at least tag your questions with relevant programming language

Answer (score 2):

More parentheses!

```
if (!($ip == $yourip && $ban == 1))
```

That should just negate the entire boolean value. The issue was that something like `!$ip` tries to negate `$ip`, which is (hopefully) not a boolean value.

Comment: Yep That fixed it! I'm afraid I cannot say thanks because I was just downvoted 3 times for doing that.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($ip != $yourip || $ban != 1)
```